# Rails 3.1 - Options_for_select values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my view should be make the following mysql query:

```
SELECT `egress_transport_documents`.* FROM `egress_transport_documents`  WHERE month(date) = 4
```

and in same view I've a drop-down menu to select witch month of the year you want choose. My issue is that, Mysql accepts only numerically values for months(1..12) while I want that in dropdown menu, user can choose between string values such as 'January','February'.. and not between '1','2'....'12' . in witch way can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using select_month helper:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_month